# Switching from Squarespace to hosted WordPress site w/ domain at GoDaddy and email through Google Apps?

Tags: google, dns, godaddy

I have a website client that has their domain with GoDaddy, website with Squarespace, and is using Google Apps for their domain's email.

We are building a new WordPress based website and will launch that soon on a recently purchased hosting plan (standard cPanel based service) while keeping Google Apps for email.

I believe that in their GoDaddy DNS editing area, we just need to do the following steps, could someone with knowledge of this confirm?

1. change A record with the heading of Host and value of @ to the IP of the new hosting account?
2. also change the nameservers to the values of the new host?
3. all the MX records stay the same and the CName records stay the same?

Thank you very much for the help. I'll attach a screenshot of the GoDaddy DNS editing area for reference, with some info crossed out.

[image: GoDaddy screenshot]

Comment: That sounds about right. I generally delete all the cnames that GoDaddy creates except www of course. It may be that you may need to keep one for your e-mail. What is nice is that changes made on GoDaddy are extremely fast. This means if something goes wrong, you can drop back and punt. Take notes.

Comment: @nh6288 1 & 3 are correct. Number 2 depends on if you're setting up custom nameservers in cPanel for your new host. If you're not (i.e., you're using GoDaddy's), then leave as is. If you are, then see the second link here: http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/664/setting-nameservers-for-your-domain-names?pc_split_value=1

Answer (score 2):

You should only need to change the single A record.

Changing your NS records mean that your DNS would be hosted by your webhost as well.  In that case you would have to re-create all of these records in their system.

Comment: +1 for a pretty basic answer, how come it took us over a year to come up with it?  :P

Comment: In this case it appears that the comments helped the user.  When that happens, it often discourages full answers, but leaves the question "unanswered".